# MKMapView / MKOverlay - allow user to define overlay coordinates

Tags: objective-c, ios4, mkmapview

I am trying to allow the user to define a border for an overlay. This seems like it should be a simple thing; but I can't even find out how to know when the user is touching the map. I would have thought that the UIMapViewDelegate would have methods to respond to the user's interactions, but it doesn't seem to. In the Google Maps app, it drops a pin when you hold on a spot; I'm guessing that would be the first step to having the user define an overlay.

It looks like the UILongPressGestureRecognizer would provide what I want; but don't quite understand how you add a GestureRecognizer to the MapView. I've read through the MKMapView and UIGestureRecognizer documentation; what am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any UIView supports having a gesture recognizer added to it with the `-addGestureRecognizer:` method. That might not be the best approach here, though: if you'd like to replicate the Maps behavior, you can use an `MKPinAnnotationView` with its `draggable` property set to `YES`, then update your overlay's boundaries to fit the annotation's position when the drag ends (i.e. when the map view calls its `-mapView:annotationView:didChangeDragState:fromOldState:` delegate method). Note that whatever annotation class you're using needs to implement a `-setCoordinate:` method, as defined in the `MKAnnotation` protocol, for pin dragging to work.

Comment: Thanks... how do I get the MKPinAnnotationView added to the place that the user is pressing on in the first place though?

Comment: Good question. I think the best approach is to have an initial “default” region set up, with, say, a pin annotation placed at each corner. It'd be more intuitive, and take less explaining in your UI, to have something already there that can be manipulated than to expect the user to place something new.

Comment: Thanks! That's probably what I'll do.